# How to do localization in SwiftUI with plurals

Tags: ios

I'm trying to build an app with localization.
In ContentView I have the following line:

```
Text("payment \(name) \(amount)")
```

For example, in the simulator this should give the following result:

"Erwin gets 1 euro."

But instead I get the following:

"payment Erwin 1"

The stringsdict file has the filename "Localizable.stringsdict" and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>payment %@ %d</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
            <string>%@ gets %#@amount@.</string>
            <key>amount</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
                <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
                <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
                <string>d</string>
                <key>zero</key>
                <string>no euros</string>
                <key>one</key>
                <string>%d euro</string>
                <key>other</key>
                <string>%d euros</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</plist<
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your last line, `</plist<` is that a copy/paste error or possibly the problem?

Comment: That's a copy/paste error. Otherwise my code wouldn't even had compiled. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem.
I started from scratch and with a lot of trail and error, I came to the conclusion that the format specifier for integers should be "%lld" instead of "%d".
The Localizable.stringsdict file now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>payment %@ %lld</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
            <string>%@ gets %#@amount@</string>
            <key>amount</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
                <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
                <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
                <string>lld</string>
                <key>zero</key>
                <string>no euros</string>
                <key>one</key>
                <string>%lld euro</string>
                <key>other</key>
                <string>%lld euros</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Enjoy the developing!